# sum function not working in group by and aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, sum, group

collection file have 2,00,000 records having multiple account_no's.

```
collection_file = collection_file.astype({'coll_amt':'int'})
collection = collection_file.groupby(['account_no']).agg({'coll_amt':'sum','coll_date':'max','gs_date':'max'}).reset_index()
```

I am trying to aggregate values to find the sum of collection amount based on account_no. But it is not summing up the values.

Comment: So column is converted to integers, no error but not sum correct? Can you add some data sample or explain more what means not sum correct ?

Comment: collection file has values like this.

Comment: ZF60786_01313705  21-04-2022 25-04-2022 25042022 10000
ZF60786_01313705  11-04-2022 13-04-2022 13042022 1869   the output should have      ZF60786_01313705 11869 but it has 1869 after executing code

Comment: @saritha: Please add the data to the question using [edit] and format it correctly. It's very hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried recreating code based on your input. For me your above code is working as expected and summing the amount correctly . You sure you checking final output dataframe 'collection' and not any other dataframe?

[image]

Comment: @saritha: Please elaborate your issue further, if issue still persist.